# ArcGIS js API - possible to get data map points from an external web service?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm very new to ArcGIS and I'm currently exploring the js API. I haven't seen documentation for this but can i use a json datasource (returned from an ajax call) as the data items/points for my map? Can anyone point me to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any Map Service (ArcGIS, WMS, KML, etc) but just a list of geometries fetched from somewhere else you must use a GraphicsLayer. You can use the default GraphicsLayer of the map or add another GraphicsLayer.

for each geometry:

```
map.graphics.add(new Graphic(geometry, symbol));
```

Comment: thank you so much! I struggled a little creating the graphic from a json object but i got it working!